# jQuery AJAX question, is this possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know how to submit a form via ajax using the jQuery $.ajax() function. My Question is, what if the form is located on another page and I load the form itself via ajax:

```
$('.contentDiv').load('form.php');
```

Can I submit this AJAX loaded form via AJAX?

Basically I have to work within the limitations of a framework that is being used. The framework only allows certain forms to be rendered and to be submitted on specific views. So the form I need to show on page A can only be rendered on page B and submitted only on page B. I can load the form on page A via ajax, but if I write the code to submit the form via ajax to it's original action (page B) on page A, will it work?

What if I write the ajax code on page B, and load both the ajax code and form on page A via ajax, will that make it work?

### UPDATE

Ok it did work. Sorry if I made it more complex than it was. Basically I put the ajax code for the form on page B and loaded both form and ajax code on page A via the load() function and when I submitted the form it updated the database fields properly from page A.

Comment: I think that will work, we need to see your 'submit-code' to say exactly.

Comment: so you have a form on A.php that is loaded via ajax and you want to read it into page B.php via another ajax call to get the contents of A.php?

Comment: accept an answer or delete your question plz

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to bind the submit action of the form element returned by $().load().

```
$('.contentDiv').load('form.php', function() {
    $('form#newFormId').submit(function() {
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url:  'submithandler.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
             //response was ok, do something
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

If you need to trigger the submit action on the form, you can also do:

```
$('form#newFormId').submit();
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question right though the form is being loaded on a php page via ajax and he's trying to get at it from another page via ajax.

Comment: Yes. But load returns that form and inserts it into the current page at .contentDiv. We can then bind to that form and submit it (to form b's action url).

Comment: the form isn't there...it's loaded on the original page via another ajax call.  so unless there is a way to fire THAT ajax call the form won't be in the payload.

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding the question...I've got a comment above to have it clarified for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple loading and executing below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('.content').load("form.php");
                $('#submit').live("click", function()
                {
                    $.ajax({url: 'form.php'});
                    return false;
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if you want to load javascript also, than you need to append head section with the loaded javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have?

A.php:

```
    <html>
       <head>
          ... include your javascript files ...
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="contentDiv"></div>
       </body>

       $(document).ready(function() {
          //some javascript stuff to make an ajax call 
          // to load form into contentDiv from source #1...
       });
    </html>
```

B.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      ... include your javascript files ...
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>

   $(document).ready(function() {
      //some javascript stuff to make an ajax call 
      // to load contents of page into body from **A.php**  ...
   });
</html>
```

If so then you have to include your javascript and CSS on both pages.  It may work with out it in some browsers but other browsers (IE) will not like it.